# Email oriented HTML WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I need a relatively simple WYSIWYG that will allow me to do a number of email compatible things. I tried [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) and some of it's offspring, but it doesn't cut it and modifying it would definitely take to much time.

What I need:

- enclosing lines in paragraph tags
- ability to align text left, right and center (using `style` attribute or at least just the outdated `center`)
- changing text size (headers and regular text would be enough)
- setting bold and italic (and maybe changing colors too)
- inserting images (just `img` tags, but hopefully with alt and title attributes)
- inserting links
- some HTML mode, to directly modify the text code

This won't be used to compose whole emails, but just parts of them (otherwise I would need to support tables and other oddities), however I need those parts to be compatible with emails (hence the requirements).

P.S. I'm looking for a free solution. This will be running on a site, so were talking about a JS library or some such.

Comment: So I just discovered that it might be feasible to write some simple WYSIWYG myself using using ContentEditable (http://html5demos.com/contenteditable).

Comment: I tried writing my own and the start was quick, but in the long run I had to give up. Handling formatting and code injection is non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo). You can choose between amount of necessary plugins for it so I think you can suit it the way you want to.

**EDIT:**

It fullfils following criteria:

- it's free
- has HTML edition mode
- it's able to change standard formatting (font size, colors, bold/italic/underline/strike)
- image and link insertion
- aligning
- JS library

Moreover it's customizable with plugins so you can remove/add other features.

**EDIT2**:
I have some experience with CKEditor during my work experience (CKEditor was integrated with JS app and Liferay), so I tested it a lot and I was really "surprised" that it works similar (in some way) with desktop text editors.